# How to validate if current date time is within Spring Cron Expression?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-scheduled

I have a Spring Cron Expression like */10 * 9-17 * * MON-FRI

I want to find out if the current time or any given time is within the range or not.

I know I can use CronExpression class and use the next() method. But it gives me the next valid runnable time.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A cron expression does not define a range or ranges of time.  Rather, it defines distinct points in time throughout a year.  In many cases, like with your example, cron expressions are viewed as describing distinct points in time throughout each week.

Since cron doesn't define a range, it doesn't make sense to ask if a particular time is "within the range or not".  This is why it has only a `next()` method...pretty much all you can do is ask what the next point in time is given a time to start from.

If this doesn't clear up your problem for you, I would suggest that you edit your question and describe your use case.  What is it that you are actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: @CrytoFool, yes i agree the usage of cron expression. However CronExpression from org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util does provide a method isSatisfiedBy(Date) to meet my requirement. The issue is that this util class is unable to parse the Spring Cron Expression. My application can receive request over http channel 24/7. Now if the request is outside the boundary of the working hours, I need to act differently.

Comment: That method's existence is interesting.  The docs for the method don't clearly state what it's doing.  My guess is that it's stating if the passed in time is one of the distinct times defined by the expression, to 1 second accuracy.  I guess I see how you could use a cron expression to effectively define ranges of time.  So what you're doing is saying "every second of every minute of hours 8-17", right?  This is technically not describing a range, but that something happens every second for certain hours, but I can see using it the way you are.  Very clever.

Comment: Why not just compare the candidate time against the start and end times for the span of time that constitutes work hours.  Is there some reason that you want/need to be able to express this as a cron expression rather than two times?

Comment: I can do that, but that means if I have to change the cron expression, then I have to change the configured start and end date time. Also I need to check if its weekend or not etc.

Comment: @Spartacus -  How about this...ask for the `next()` time and compare it with the time you passed in.  If they differ by 10 minutes or less, then you're in the zone.  You might need to play with the edge cases, times near the start and end of the day.  That might be as easy as subtracting 10 minutes from the  time value you're testing.  You'd obviously also have to deal with the frequency being something other than 10 minutes if that varies.  How hard that would be would depend on the constraints you can put on your cron expressions.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to check if a time matches a specific cron, if you truncate a given timestamp to seconds and do a little tweaking with `CronExpression#next()`. Basically it'll ask "is the current timestamp a valid time for cron execution", even if it isn't really a range.

Within `CronExpression#next()` we can see it calls `#nextOrSame()` by adding 1 nanosecond to it:

```java
@Nullable
public <T extends Temporal & Comparable<? super T>> T next(T temporal) {
    return nextOrSame(ChronoUnit.NANOS.addTo(temporal, 1));
}
```

Unfortunately, `#nextOrSame()` is private and we can't call it. But we can "undo" the 1 nanosecond addition. So if we want to compare if a date matches a given cron, we could do something like:

```java
CronExpression expression = CronExpression.parse("*/10 * 9-17 * * MON-FRI");
LocalDateTime testTime = LocalDateTime.of(2023, 1, 13, 10, 0, 0);
LocalDateTime truncatedTime = testTime.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS); // Truncate to seconds, as cronjobs run with seconds precision
LocalDateTime truncatedExpressionOffset = truncatedTime.minusNanos(1L); // Offsets the +1 in expression#next(), since #nextOrSame() is private.
LocalDateTime nextExpression = expression.next(truncatedExpressionOffset);
System.out.printf("Current time [%s] matches expression [%s]: [%s]", truncatedTime, expression, truncatedTime.equals(nextExpression));
```

If you play a bit with the timestamp (13th being a Friday):

```
Time [2023-01-13T10:00] matches expression [*/10 * 9-17 * * MON-FRI]: [true]
Time [2023-01-13T10:00:05] matches expression [*/10 * 9-17 * * MON-FRI]: [false]
Time [2023-01-12T09:00:20] matches expression [*/10 * 9-17 * * MON-FRI]: [true]
Time [2023-01-12T08:00:20] matches expression [*/10 * 9-17 * * MON-FRI]: [false]
Time [2023-01-14T09:00:20] matches expression [*/10 * 9-17 * * MON-FRI]: [false]
```

It's a bit of a workaround to "undo" the 1 nanosecond and call `next()`. But with some unit tests on this you can be prepared if internals do change when upgrading.